# Android 12 with Activity Recreat Function

Tags: android

Currently in my application I support multiple languages, and some of them requires RTL support,
so after changing the language in the app I call recreat(), it was working fine until I upgraded my phone to Android 12 (One UI skin) it is just changing the strings of the app but not re arranging the place if layout, ex. 
start is left for English, but it is right for Arabic. 
for now I am using workaround to overcome this, which is, when ever the user changes the language, I launch the main activity again with clearing the stack. 
Any suggestions? or is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: If it works why bother? anyway here is a github project https://github.com/JakeWharton/ProcessPhoenix

Comment: @UrielFrankel I am not sure if it is the best way to do it or not, that's why I am trying to find what is the best way to do that and if I am doing something that is not recommended, and thank you for sharing this